# How to say "to found a new company over a previous one"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I was just wondering how to state a company which exists today was actually "founded over" a previous one.

i.e. If X Company was sold in 1950 and new owner of the company founded a new company called Y Company by also changing the mission, vision, objectives and working field of the company, what would go in the following sentence?:

> Y company was *{founded over}* X company

Answer (score 3):

Company Y **succeeded/superseded/supplanted** Company X.

From oxforddictionaries.com:

> **[succeed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/succeed)**
> *VERB*
>
> **2.2** *Come after and take the place of*: her embarrassment was succeeded by fear
>
> Synonyms: **follow**, come after, follow after;
> take the place of, replace; **subsequent**, successive,
> following, ensuing, later, future, next, coming
>
> **[supersede](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supersede)**
> *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Take the place of (a person or thing previously in authority or use); supplant: the older models of car have now been
> superseded
>
> Synonyms:  replace, supplant, take the place of, take over from,
> substitute for, displace, oust, overthrow, remove, unseat, override;
> succeed, come after, step into the shoes of
> *informal* crowd out, fill someone's boots
>
> **[supplant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supplant)**
> *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Supersede and replace: domestic production has been supplanted by
> imports and jobs have been lost
>
> Synonyms:  replace, displace, supersede, take the place of, take over
> from, substitute for, undermine, override;  oust, usurp, overthrow,
> remove, topple, unseat, depose, dethrone, eject, dispel; succeed, come
> after, step into the shoes of

Company Y is called the *successor* (company).

From [smallbusiness.chron.com](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/successor-company-23022.html):

> Entrepreneurs create business ideas that can be transformed into a
> small business. Sometimes the business will not succeed because of
> factors that may include financing or marketing. In these situations,
> ***successor** companies* can arise from the previous company after liquidation. They are also referred to as "*Phoenix*" companies because
> they rise out of the ashes of the previous company.